# Xcode 4.3.1 install failure

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, installation

I have a Mac Mini with Lion (10.7.2). I downloaded a version of Xcode (4.3.1) from an other workstation (Windows) and I tried to install it. But I receive this strange error message !

http://systemsboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/xcode03.png

My error message is slightly different (I have a direct link to var/log/install.log)

Of course, I check the logs but there's no informations concerning this failure. There is anyone that encountered the same problem. My only solution right now is to download again Xcode but my connection sucks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try getting it through the Mac App Store instead.

Comment: I tried it, but i got another problem with that. When i try to download it, here's the error i got : 
impossible to complete the purchase
Unable to verify file distribution. It may be damaged or unsigned.

like this screenshot : http://forums.macgeneration.com/mac-app-store/installation-xcode-avec-mac-app-store-834682.html

Comment: Maybe it's picking up the installer you downloaded previously, as in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068900/how-to-force-installation-of-xcode

Comment: Well, I downloaded again xCode and it works ! Probably a corrupted file. Thanks anyway